# How to get full field's id in view?

Tags: django

It's easy for templates: `{{ field.id_for_label }}`, but how to do same in view?

I need to get full id (with `id_` and `prefix`). I can calculate it, but maybe is there a simpler way?

**Update:** I want to make a dictionary like `{field_id: field_error_message}` and send it back to browser as json response.

Comment: Please post your code, I don't know what you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In view you can do the same - get the `id_for_label` property of the bound form field:

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> class MyForm(forms.Form):
...     name = forms.CharField()
... 
>>> form = MyForm(prefix='myform')
>>> form['name'].id_for_label
u'id_myform-name'
>>>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, I tried `form.fields['name'].id_for_label` and `form.fields['name'].widget.id_for_label` instead of this :(